# How to extend/modify an existing Laravel Nova field?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I'd like to modify the `Code` component of Laravel Nova. For example in the file:
`vendor/laravel/nova/resources/js/components/Detail/CodeField.vue`

I'd like to modify the `config` object near the bottom, specifically, I'd like to change the following line to `false`:

`indentWithTabs: true,`

How would I go about modifying this value and having it persist with the ephemeral nature of the `vendor` folder?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can "modify" an existing Field, but you can create the same Field containing the same logic, and adding your customizations as described [here](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html).

You can also check if you're able to extend a custom field and override it - as described [here](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/96).

You could also try to apply this change in the [root repository](https://github.com/laravel/nova/blob/3.0/resources/js/components/Detail/CodeField.vue) and check if the maintainers of nova will apply this change.